# Artifacts in Objects and meshes in viewport V2.81

Tags: rendering, mesh, artifacts

Can anyone please tell me how to remove these artifacts in meshes and objects in the viewport. It happens with any mesh or object I place whether it's a low poly or high. This has never happened to me in other versions. I've tried all the render Engines but nothing changes. I'm sure is some setting some where but I don't know where it could possibly be. I have dual graphics card and a pretty high end computer. GeForce GTX 980 TI and Intel Core i7 6700K CPU 4.00GHZ if that matters

Thanks you!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>N</kbd> to open up the properties panel. Probably  you are near value 0.0001m, try to change it to 0.1m. Also try changing the end clip to 1000m.

Comment: If you were sitting right next to me I would give you a big fat KISS! Thank you!!! THat solved the problem